# Cannot use Wi-Fi on wireless devices when PC is on

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

My ISP's line is provided via an ethernet cable which runs into a wi-fi router. Another ethernet cable runs from the router to my PC. So basically the PC is connected to the internet via ethernet cable and other wireless devices (phones, laptops) connect via router. Now, this problem only started after buying my new PC 3 months back - never noticed it on my old PC. Sometimes, whenever I my PC is on none of the other wireless devices (phones, laptops) get any speed at all. Sometimes, the devices just shows 'connected, no internet'. But internet works just fine on the PC. Interestingly, when the problem appears, immediately when I turn the PC off, all the other devices can normally connect to the internet - no problem whatsoever. I can assure you this is not because my PC was downloading something in the background because Task Manager would show almost no network activity. What's more, this problem happens seemingly at random, that is it doesn't happen all the time when my PC is on. What could cause this? My ISP can't provide any solution, they checked the router and said all was fine. And because the problem occurred at random, all the devices conveniently connected to all devices when their technician came to the house to check for problems. -_-

I am using a Tenda router - one with 3 antennae, for the exact name.

My old PC config - Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GB RAM, forgot the motherboard

My new PC config - AMD Ryzen 5 3600, 32 GB RAM, RX 570 8GB GPU, motherboard - Gigabyte B450 S2H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I fixed the problem but I'm not entirely sure how. Basically, the router was positioned in a lower position beside the computer case on my computer table. It was not crammed in any way, and it was a bit away from my wall so I thought there was enough air flow, but it was still a lower position. About a bit more than a week ago, I changed the position of my router and placed it on top of the desk where my monitor is. So now, it is exposed to a lot more fresh cooler air, I imagine. I have not seen the problem since then, it's like it magically disappeared. Now, I'm not sure, but it is my theory that maybe in that lower position beside the computer case, it was exposed to a much hotter air whenever the PC was running since you know, under load the PC fans would push out all the air. Thus the processors and chips in my router could not efficiently cool themselves maybe. But now exposed to much cooler and fresher air - probably the processor can work much more efficiently all the time and thus the problem perhaps disappeared. The problem was extremely random as I have mentioned earlier, and it could make a return any time but since the problem has not shown up in more than 10 days, God willing, it won't return again. So, I'm declaring the problem as gone for now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have somehow turned your PC and your router into a bridged connection, with the PC acting as a sub-router or switch. You can either check that your router is indeed *routing* traffic to and fro (enable DHCP through the admin page every router has), or turn your PC into a WiFi router of its own, and connect your other devices to it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. A friend of mine told me the same thing and told me to enable DHCP and change the end IP from ***.***.*.200 to ***.***.*.199. Let's see if it works. So far, no problem this whole evening.

Comment: Okay, so it seemed like it was all fixed yesterday only for the problem to return today. I made sure DHCP is enabled. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: How many Ethernet ports are there on your router? On some hardware, there's a specific Ethernet port (usually with a yellow surrounding) to connect a router or a switch. This one preempts all the bandwidth. If you plugged your router-to-PC Ethernet cable into this port, it could explain why the other devices can't connect to the Internet. Have you tried a different Ethernet port for your old PC?

Comment: Okay so the ethernet cable from my ISP runs into the ethernet port on my router marked 'WAN'. Other than that there are three ethernet ports - all yellow colored (including the one marked 'WAN') I don't remember which port for my old PC, but my current PC - yes, I tried plugging it into different ports (except the 'WAN' one).

Comment: The WAN Ethernet port is for connecting another router or a switch, not a PC. Use one of the others, reboot your PC so that it force-gets a new DHCP address from the router, and check if the other devices can connect to the Internet.

Comment: No, no. My PC cable isn't connected to the WAN port. Also, now I've discovered a new phenomenon. Even when I disconnect the Ethernet cable to my PC, I still cannot get internet on other devices. I have to completely shut my PC off.

Comment: It could be several things, then: Maybe there's a limit in your router as to how many different devices can be connected at the same time. You'd have to log in your router's admin page to check up on that. Maybe whitelisting MAC addresses is enabled on the router, and you have to register your new devices one by one with it. If you're sure DHCP is enabled on the router, and your old PC isn't plugged into the WAN port, I'm out of ideas for the moment. While your devices are connected to it, regardless of how, reboot your router, just in case. It'll renew the DHCP lease for all of them.

Comment: Additionally, looking it up on the Internet, I see your router *may* be switched to extender mode. This could have consequences on how many devices it caters at any given moment, because routing would be turned off. Go into the router property page (192.168.0.1) and check if "Universal repeater" is off. If it's on, turn it off. The router will reboot.

Comment: Wait, I think I could not explain this properly. I only have one PC connected to the router - my new one. The old one is not connected in any way. Universal repeater is turned off - in fact wireless repeating is disabled. And how do I force-get a new DHCP address for my PC?

Comment: OK, I got your setup wrong, then, but it's clearer now. On your PC, press Windows-X to trigger the so-called Power menu, and choose Command line (admin), provided you have admin rights on this PC, of course. If so, type "ipconfig /all" (no quotes; press Enter) to get a reading of your network settings, then type "ipconfig /release" (Enter), "ipconfig /renew" (Enter). Leave your DNS cache alone for the moment (no "ipconfig /flushdns"), reboot your PC, and the DHCP lease will be renewed. Your router will probably attribute the same IP as before, but that's not certain. Tell us how it went.